# How to fix this class template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a class, that in the simplest example works as follows:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename NumberType>
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        SomeClass(NumberType a_) : a(a_) {}
        void get_number() 
        {
            if (typeid(NumberType) == typeid(std::complex<double>))
                std::cout << a.real() << " " << a.imag() << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
    private:
        NumberType a;
};

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    std::complex<double> c(2.0,3);

    SomeClass<int> A(a);    
    A.get_number();

    SomeClass<std::complex<double>> C(c);
    C.get_number();

    return 0;
}
```

It basically prints any real number as it is but it should split the complex number in two two reals.

If I compile it as it is shown, the error message is as follows

```
 In instantiation of 'void SomeClass<NumberType>::get_number() [with NumberType = int]':
28:18:   required from here
14:46: error: request for member 'imag' in '((SomeClass<int>*)this)->SomeClass<int>::a', which is of non-class type 'int'
14:27: error: request for member 'real' in '((SomeClass<int>*)this)->SomeClass<int>::a', which is of non-class type 'int'
```

I understand that since `a` is of type `int` in the first case, I can not use `imag()` on it, hence the error message.

How can I modify this class so that it does what I need in case of arbitrary `NumberType` template arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use templates and template specialization, not `typeid`—in C++ you want to use compile-time abstractions rather than making runtime decisions about the type of a variable or a value.

You can have the following freestanding helper functions:

```
// General case:
template <typename T>
void get_number(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

// Specialization for complex<double>
template <>
void get_number<std::complex<double> >(const std::complex<double>& value)
{
    std::cout << value.real() << " " << value.imag() << std::endl;
}

// ... More specializations if you need to.
```

Now you can call:

```
get_number(3);
get_number(std::complex<double>(1, 2));
```

To make it more generic, you can use `std::complex<T>` instead of `std::complex<double>`. That needs a little more work because function template partial specialization is not supported. You need to make get_number a static member of a helper struct as follows:

```
// General case:
template <typename T>
struct get_number_helper {
    static void get(const T& value)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
 };

// Specialization for complex<T>
template <typename T>
struct get_number_helper<std::complex<T> > {
    static void get(const std::complex<T>& value)
    {
        std::cout << value.real() << " " << value.imag() << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void get_number(const T& value)
{
    get_number_helper<T>::get(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As alexc already mentioned you should use template specifications to prevent the compiler to *see* the `std::complex<>::real` or `imag` member when you use `int` or `double` as data type.

**Member** template specifications are closer to what you already have:

```c++
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template<typename NumberType>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(NumberType a_) : a(a_) {}
    void get_number() {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }

private:
    NumberType a;
};

template<>
void SomeClass<std::complex<double> >::get_number() {
    std::cout << a.real() << " " << a.imag() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    std::complex<double> c(2.0,3);

    SomeClass<int> A(a);    
    A.get_number();

    SomeClass<std::complex<double> > C(c);
    C.get_number();

    return 0;
}
```